# Select specific columns in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I want to select part of the columns from Excel, but not all of them. What query should I use?
My query works if I use `select *`, but not 4 specific columns.

I am using an OLEDB connection string. The result I get when I run my query is:

> No value given for one or more required parameters

Comment: I am getting

 No value given for one or more required parameters

Comment: Please, provide the source code you're using, the name of the workbook of the Excel file and the column names inside the Sheet.

Comment: @Oscar Mederos I managed to get required o/p by applying other logic instead of using query for particular columns.

Comment: @ Oscar Mederos Thanks for your response! :)